# Does the line y=mx have equal intercepts?

Tags: geometry, definition

This line passes through the origin and has zero intercepts.

Can this be called as a line having equal intercepts?

What is the definition of intercepts of a line then?

Comment: A line can have x-intercepts and y-intercepts. $y=mx$ has $0$ for both. But normally we don't say it has equal intercepts.

Comment: @Fred What is your definition of *equal intercepts*?

Comment: @flawr According to me it is a line having a slope of +1 or -1 but this doesn't cover this case. So I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

The general equation of a straight line is $ax+by+c=0$ and the intercept with the $x$ axis is the point with $y=0$, i.e.

$x=\dfrac{-c}{a}$ , $y=0$

the intercept with the $y$ axis is the point with $x=0$, i.e

$ x=0$ , $y=\dfrac{-c}{b}$

So you see that the two intercepts are all null iff $c=0$.  If $c \ne 0$ than the intercepts have the same value if $ a=b$.

Comment: So can it be called as a line having equal intercepts?

Comment: Yes. you can also see .http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Intercept_form

Comment: But the link says _since it violates the rule_. So y=mx 's intercepts are not defined?

Comment: In this case the intercepts are $0$.